# When I add up in my pointer address it points to my array? Why? Reference and Dereference confusion C++

Tags: c++, pointers, dereference, pointer-arithmetic, addressof

In this example,
I have an array of four elements. I have declared a pointer to integer which contains the address of array. Then i have displayed the address of 0th index in 3 different ways. Similarly, the address of 1st index is displayed in 3 different ways. When I output this (&pNumbers)+0 its pretty understandable that a unique and different address would be displayed. In next line, *(&pNumbers+0) displays the 0th index address (as its contain by the pointer). Now the problem part comes. On outputting this (&pNumbers)+1 line it displays the array 0th index again. Why ?

first question:
when i retrieve the pointers address (&pNumbers), it displays new and unique address. But when i add up in that address. How is it accessing the array's element addresses?
e.g

```
enter code here

cout<<" (&pNumbers)+1 "<<(&pNumbers)+1<<endl // new address + 1 but showing address of 0 element.

cout<<" (&pNumbers + 2) "<<(&pNumbers+2)<<endl // showing address of of 1st index
```

second question:
If say it does somehow points to the corresponding array elements. On my dereferencing why it is not displaying the correct data value corresponding to array elements. 
e.g

```
enter code here
cout<<" *(&pNumbers+1) "<< *(&pNumbers+1) // assumption was 31 (but displaying some 0x1f)

cout<<" *(&pNumbers + 2) "<<*(&pNumbers+2)<<endl // assumption was 28 (but displpaying 0x1c)
```

Below is the source code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{int number[] = { 31, 28, 31, 30};
    int *pNumbers = number;

    cout<<" Address of number[0] "<<number<<endl;
    cout<<" Address of number[1] "<<number+1<<endl;
    cout<<" Address of number[2] "<<number+2<<endl;
    cout<<" Address of number[3] "<<number+3<<endl<<endl;

    cout<<" Address of &pNumbers "<< &pNumbers<<endl<<endl; // address of pNumbers

    cout<<" Address of number "<< number<<endl; // address of array's first element
    cout<<" pNumber Address "<< pNumbers<<endl;
    cout<<" &(pNumbers[0]) "<< &(pNumbers[0])<<endl<<endl;

    cout << " pNumbers+1:  " << pNumbers+1<<endl; //address of array's second element
    cout<<" (&pNumbers[1]) "<<(&pNumbers[1])<<endl; //
    cout<<" (pNumbers+1) "<< (pNumbers+1) <<endl<<endl;

    cout<<" (&pNumbers)+0 "<< (&pNumbers)+0<<endl;
    cout<<" *(&pNumbers+0) "<< *(&pNumbers+0)<<endl<<endl;

    cout<<" (&pNumbers)+1 "<<(&pNumbers)+1<<endl<<endl; // new address + 1 expected but displaying array's 0th index address why ?
    cout<<" *(&pNumbers+1) "<<*(&pNumbers+1)<<endl<<endl;

    cout<<" (&pNumbers + 2) "<<(&pNumbers+2)<<endl<<endl;
    cout<<" *(&pNumbers + 2) "<<*(&pNumbers+2)<<endl<<endl;

    cout<<" (&pNumbers + 3) "<<(&pNumbers+3)<<endl<<endl;
    cout<<" *(&pNumbers + 3) "<<*(&pNumbers+3)<<endl<<endl;

    cout<<" (&pNumbers + 4) "<<(&pNumbers+4)<<endl<<endl;
    cout<<" *(&pNumbers + 4) "<<*(&pNumbers+4)<<endl<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `assumption was 31 (but displaying some 0x1f)` 0x1f in hexdecimal **is** 31 in decimal.

Comment: I would assume it's because pNumbers is on the stack right before numbers[], this will be compiler dependent, and indeed when I run it I see different output.

Comment: And for your second question, the number 28 in base ten *is* the same number as 0x1C in hexadecimal. They are equal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is memory layout of your stack on most platforms.
[image: your stack]

> On outputting this (&pNumbers)+1 line it displays the array 0th index again. Why ?

Your code gets address of `pNumbers` memory cell (type of `&pNumbers` is `int **`), then adds one to it which semantics is to increment it by size of pointer, so expression `&pNumbers + 1` is an address of your original array as `pNumbers` variable is a pointer itself.

To your second question what expression `*(&pNumbers+1)` is doing is basically trying to interpret memory location which stores `int` as pointer to int (type of `*(&pNumbers+1)` in `int *`). This is the reason why you see your int in hex instead to dec format. In other words you treat `number[0]` as `int *` and print it.

What can be confusing in all this stuff is that array is treated as pointer to its first element which causes that `number` and `&number` is essentially the same address (but both expressions has different types)

Hope could help.

Comment: Thanks for replying :)
I pretty much understood the reason of second question. But am still a bit stuck on question 1.

Comment: Above the line `int *pNumbers = number;` add another line `int x = 0;` and look what `(&pNumbers)+1` is. It will be the same as `&x` (on your particaular archtecture). So `&pNumbers+1` points to whatever is on your stack declared before `pNumbers`.

Comment: Yikes, I am afraid its not happening as you have stated in your explanation. 


   number[0] address 0x28fee0,
   number[1] address 0x28fee4,
   number[2] address 0x28fee8,
   number[3] address 0x28feec,

  &pNumbers  address  0x28fedc,
  &x address  0x28fed8,
 (&pNumbers)+1 address 0x28fee0,

Comment: It looks like you put declaration of `x` below declaration of `pNumbers` as `pNumbers` variable has greater address than `x`. And make sure to disable optimizations in your compiler, with gcc you can use -O0, maybe for some reason your compiler rearange your declarations.